Como crear estructutra YML desada con writeYML de Utility Steps
Actualmente estoy intentando crear un yml dinamico para un archivo de host de Ansible y lo estoy haciendo con writeYML de Utility Steps de Jenkins, ya cree la estructura el detalle esta cuando finaliza la creacion del YML me coloca con algunos caracteres como ( | , ') y quisiera eliminar esos caracteres o de que otra manera pudiera contruir el YML con la estructura que requiero.
El caracter | me lo coloca automaticamente cuando creo la lista - ips...
Nota: El YML se construye de manera dinamica y todos los datos que inyecto al contruir el YML de igual menera se toman a partir de un JSON.
De momento solo he provado con el writeYML y readYML de Utility Steps de Jenkins ya que me ha funcionado a excepcion de los caracteres que me coloca al construir el YML.
Anexo ejemplo de lo que se genera con Jenkins:
all:
  children:
    zona_a:
      vars:
        instancia_ports: '[8549,8550,8551]'
        admin_ips: |
          - ips: ''
            balancer: ''
              - ip: 10.82.57.111
              - ip: 10.82.57.112
            pool_member: /Common/pool_test_443
            puerto: [8549,8550,8551]


Ejemplo de como deseo la estructura final:
all:
  children:
    zona_a:
      vars:
        instancia_ports: [8549,8550,8551]
        admin_ips: 
          - ips: 
            balancer: 
              - ip: 10.82.57.111
              - ip: 10.82.57.112
            pool_member: /Common/pool_test_443
            puerto: [8549,8550,8551]



La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil reproducir tu problema, identificar el error y responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Siempre me hace mucha gracia cuando alguien afirma "Uso esto porque me está funcionando, solo que...", a ver, o funciona o no. No te está funcionando porque lo que te devuelve no es válido :)
